# Does there exist a "quadratic" reverse triangle inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, reference-request, vector-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x,y$ be some vectors.

The triangle inequality states
$$-\|x - y\| \leq \|x\| - \|y\| \leq \|x - y\|$$

Is it also true that:

$$-\|x - y\|^2 \leq \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2 \leq \|x - y\|^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: take the scalar case where $x=2,y=1$.

Comment: Does $$-\|x - y\|^2 \leq \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2$$ hold?

Comment: Counterexample to that: x=1,y=2

Comment: Does anything hold?

Comment: Sure, the regular triangle inequality holds

Comment: @CuraçaoHajek You can square both sides of the regular inequality to get $$\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2\|x\|\|y\|\leq \|x-y\|^2$$

Comment: Maybe the Parallelogram equation might be something which could help you :$||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2 = 2(||x||^2+||y||^2)$